# Cannot use MongoDB driver "mongodb-driver-sync" in OSGi Project: Unable to resolve

Tags: mongodb, osgi, driver, apache-karaf

We are developing an OSGi application running on Apache Karaf. Our application uses Apache Camel and MongoDB.

First we **successfully used a quite old version of "mongo-java-driver"** (3.12.11): By adding this dependency to the modules `pom.xml` and to the `osgi feature repository` we were able to start our application and connect to MongoDB:

pom.xml (maven module1)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

feature.xml:

```
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/3.18.4/xml/features</repository>

    <feature name="module1" description="An OSGi module" version="1.0.1-SNAPSHOT">
        <feature>scr</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true">aries-blueprint</feature>
        <feature>camel-core</feature>
        <feature>camel-blueprint</feature>
        <feature>camel-cxf</feature>
        <feature>camel-xslt-saxon</feature>
        <feature>camel-jetty</feature>
        <feature>camel-rabbitmq</feature>
        <feature>camel-openapi-java</feature>
        <feature>camel-jackson</feature>
        <capability>osgi.service;objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler;osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint;effective:=active;
        </capability>

        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.11</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:my.own.project/module1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
    </feature>
```

**But that driver is legacy, quite old and missing important features, so we would like to use a modern driver, namely mongodb-driver-sync (version 4.8.2).**

**We replaced the previous driver with "mongodb-driver-sync":**

pom.xml (maven module1)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

feature.xml:

```
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/3.18.4/xml/features</repository>

    <feature name="module1" description="An OSGI module" version="1.0.1-SNAPSHOT">
        <feature>scr</feature>
        <feature prerequisite="true">aries-blueprint</feature>
        <feature>camel-core</feature>
        ...
        <!-- <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.11</bundle>-->

        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/4.8.1</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:my.own.project/module1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
    </feature>
```

This fails when starting the feature in Karaf:

```
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity;
osgi.identity=mesh; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.1.SNAPSHOT,1.0.1.SNAPSHOT]";
filter:="(&(osgi.identity=mesh)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=1.0.1.SNAPSHOT)(version<=1.0.1.SNAPSHOT))" 
[caused by: Unable to resolve mesh/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [mesh/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=mesh-vms-tso01; type=karaf.feature 
[caused by: Unable to resolve mesh-vms-tso01/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [mesh-vms-tso01/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=mesh-vms-tso01; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1.SNAPSHOT,1.0.1.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory 
[caused by: Unable to resolve mesh-vms-tso01/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [mesh-vms-tso01/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.btc.mesh.core.camel)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))" 
[caused by: Unable to resolve mesh-core/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT: 
missing requirement [mesh-core/1.0.1.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.mongodb)(version>=4.8.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))"]]]]
```

I also tried version 4.1.0 because an older documentation mentioned that it is a valid OSGI bundle:

> The mongodb-driver-sync artifact is a valid OSGi bundle whose symbolic
> name is org.mongodb.driver-sync."

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver/getting-started/installation/

**But we also had no luck.** Does the symbolic name help in any way?

After version 4.3.x the documentation moved from `mongodb.github.io` to `www.mongodb.com` and the reference to OSGi has been removed. The MANIFEST file of all mentioned drivers looks quite similar including the bundle information. So, AFAIK , OSGi should work. Very confusing.

**So, we need your help**

- Has anyone more information about a modern MongoDB driver which is ready for OSGI?
- Or maybe we are doing something wrong when integrating the driver into our OSGI module?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution myself this afternoon somewhere in the following note and it works well with version 4.8.2 of the mongodb sync driver:

> If integrating the drivers JAR file directly into a project, then you
> should also add the JARs of bson and mondodb.driver.core.

Apparently this is also necessary when defining the dependency for OSGi:

```
<feature name="sample version="1.0.1-SNAPSHOT">
    ...
   <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.mongodb/bson/4.8.2</bundle>
   <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.8.2</bundle>
   <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/4.8.2</bundle>
</feature>
```

**I’m wondering if this is really the right way. Maybe someone can confirm that for me.**

Of course it would be great if everyone could find the solution in the documentation. Maybe that can be integrated?!

Overall OSGi doesn’t seem to be very common anymore, especially in documentation. IMHO, OSGi is still a wonderful technology that represents a great compromise between microservices where each service runs in its own java runtime and (deployment) monoliths!